# Thematics in Mapinfo - multiple intervals from same table?

Tags: mapinfo, thematic-map

I´ve got a table where I want to thematize intervals of values like between 0.1 - 1.0, 1.0 - 2.0 and etc., but I´m almost sure that´s not possible, whithout splitting up the table to multiple tables, right? It has to be for Mapinfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a theme using Ranges.

In the dialog 'Create Thematic Map - Step 3 og 3', you can click the 'Ranges...' button to changes the intervals.

In the 'Customize Ranges" dialog you can pick 'Custom' from the Method list and then enter your preferred intervals.